The browser displays the status of the validator
Why are some consensus nodes both active and waiting?



I think that validator will be waiting status in the next session
You can see the symbol Next Session, only 1 active validator, the remaining validators are waiting/inactive in the next session


Maybe your guess is correct, because I observed that they did not repeat in Active and Waiting in the first few epochs of an era.
